# Limit queries in custom Rails4 model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Trying Ruby on Rails I am fiddling around making a small application. So far I like the rails way. I have a model **Administration** which has a **Manager** and an **Organisation**.

I want to make sure - using validations - that the manager assigned to the adminisration is associated to the organisation the administrator belongs to.

I have a working validation, but my gut-feeling says it's expensive on queries.

```
class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :organisation
    belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'manager_id'

    validates :code, numericality: true
    validates :manager_id, :presence => true
    validates :organisation_id, :presence => true
    validates :code, uniqueness: { scope: :organisation_id, message: 'BB: Code already in use' }

    validate :manager_belongs_to_organisation

    def manager_belongs_to_organisation
        errors.add(:base, 'BB: Manager does not exist') unless Organisation.find(self.organisation_id).users.include?(User.find(self.manager_id))
    end
end
```

Any thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to work around this issue is to assign only manager to `Administration`. `organization_id` is then automatically inserted using `before_save` callback:

```
class Administration
   ...

   before_save :update_organization_id

   ...

   def update_organization_id
     self.organization_id = self.manager.organization_id
   end
end
```

Comment: Your solution works for me! This is what happens with ad-hoc coding. But hey... that's what fiddling is good for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are more problems with your data model.
Please don't forget about [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In your `Administration` model your check relations beetween `Manager` and `Organization`. 
This is bad idea in general.

Is your manager has only one organization? If so, better solution is to store only manager for `Administration`, and call `administration.manager.organization` when you need it. And add validation to your `Manager` model:

```
validates :organization, presence: true
```

Comment: A manager doesn't manage an organisation, but 1 or more administrations. Dimakura has pointed me in the right direction.